# drupal best performance: too many tpls?

Tags: performance, drupal

I'm developing a new drupal 7 theme, and I was wondering whether using template files for every markup block/view/region or using hook functions in template.php will perform better.

Comment: this qustion is too vague: both ways have their merrits and drawbacks and in general, depending on the goal of the site, a mixture nets usually the best performance (performance being an ambigious term in the first place..). what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i'm talking generally, if i have an option to edit markup of some block/view/etc file in both ways, make a new tpl for it or in template.php with a function, which way is the best ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect answer. If you site is correctly configured, there shouldn't be much performance difference.

While there may be debate on this, it really comes down to whether you are more comfortable in the theming realm, and prefer to build templates, or the coding realm, and prefer building functions in template.php.